# Auto Complete user address field using Google API

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I use Google API to autocomplete address on my HTML form. I did manage to get it to work, however, when I try to pass the auto completed address to different fields such as street number, street address, city, state, country, postcode it is not populating on their respective fileds. I've added my code below - any suggestion would be really appreciated:

HTML Code:

```
     <TR>
    <TD>
          <SPAN ID=_Datalead_enteryouraddress class=VIEWBOX >
          <input type="text" CLASS=EDIT ID="autocomplete" name="lead_enteryouraddress"  value="" maxlength=40 placeholder='Enter your address:*' onFocus="geolocate()" required>
          <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_enteryouraddress" id="_HIDDENlead_enteryouraddress" value="" entryType="10">
          </SPAN>
    </TD>
  </TR>  
  <TR>
    <TD>
          <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companyaddress1 class=VIEWBOX >
          <input type="text" CLASS=EDIT ID="lead_companyaddress1" disabled="true" name="lead_companyaddress1" value="" maxlength=40 placeholder='Street Number:*' required>
          <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companyaddress1" id="_HIDDENlead_companyaddress1" value="" entryType="10">
          </SPAN>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
          <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companyaddress2 class=VIEWBOX >
          <input type="text" CLASS=EDIT ID="lead_companyaddress2" disabled="true" name="lead_companyaddress2"  value="" maxlength=40 placeholder='Street Name:*' required>
          <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companyaddress2" id="_HIDDENlead_companyaddress2" value="" entryType="10">
          </SPAN>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
          <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companycity class=VIEWBOX >
          <input type="text" CLASS="jointodesc" disabled="true" ID="lead_companycity" name="lead_companycity"  value="" maxlength=30 placeholder='Suburb:*' required>
          <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companycity" id="_HIDDENlead_companycity" value="" entryType="10">
          </SPAN>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
          <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companystate class=VIEWBOX >
          <input type="text" CLASS="EDIT" disabled="true" ID="lead_companystate" name="lead_companystate"  value="" maxlength=30 placeholder='State:*' required>
          <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companystate" id="_HIDDENlead_companystate" value="" entryType="10">
          </SPAN>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
          <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companypostcode class=VIEWBOX >
          <input type="text" CLASS=EDIT ID="lead_companypostcode" disabled="true" name="lead_companypostcode"  value="" maxlength=10 placeholder='Post Code:*' required>
          <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companypostcode" id="_HIDDENlead_companypostcode" value="" entryType="10">
          </SPAN>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
          <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companycountry class=VIEWBOX >
          <input type="text" CLASS=EDIT ID="lead_companycountry" disabled="true" name="lead_companycountry"  value="" maxlength=10 placeholder='Country:*' required>
          <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companycountry" id="_HIDDENlead_companycountry" value="" entryType="10">
          </SPAN>
    </TD>
  </TR>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script>
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
        lead_companyaddress1: 'short_name',  
        lead_companyaddress2: 'long_name',   
        lead_companycity: 'long_name',
        lead_companystate: 'short_name',
        lead_companycountry: 'long_name',
        lead_companypostcode: 'short_name'
      };

      function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }

      // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
      // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }
</script>
```

URL to the form: https://www.supremeheating.com.au/test-form-4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) depends on the ids of the elements being the same as those in the response data.

Simplest fix is to change the `componentForm` object back to what it was in the example:

```
const componentForm = {
  street_number: "short_name",
  route: "long_name",
  locality: "long_name",
  administrative_area_level_1: "short_name",
  country: "long_name",
  postal_code: "short_name",
};
```

And change your element ids to match:

```
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <SPAN ID=_Datalead_enteryouraddress class=VIEWBOX>
        <input type="text" CLASS=EDIT ID="autocomplete" name="lead_enteryouraddress" value="" maxlength=40 placeholder='Enter your address:*' onFocus="geolocate()" required>
        <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_enteryouraddress" id="_HIDDENlead_enteryouraddress" value="" entryType="10">
      </SPAN>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companyaddress1 class=VIEWBOX>
        <input type="text" CLASS=EDIT ID="street_number" disabled="true" name="street_number" value="" maxlength=40 placeholder='Street Number:*' required>
        <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companyaddress1" id="_HIDDENlead_companyaddress1" value="" entryType="10">
      </SPAN>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companyaddress2 class=VIEWBOX>
        <input type="text" CLASS=EDIT ID="route" disabled="true" name="route" value="" maxlength=40 placeholder='Street Name:*' required>
        <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companyaddress2" id="_HIDDENlead_companyaddress2" value="" entryType="10">
      </SPAN>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companycity class=VIEWBOX>
        <input type="text" CLASS="jointodesc" disabled="true" ID="locality" name="locality" value="" maxlength=30 placeholder='Suburb:*' required>
        <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companycity" id="_HIDDENlead_companycity" value="" entryType="10">
      </SPAN>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companystate class=VIEWBOX>
        <input type="text" CLASS="EDIT" disabled="true" ID="administrative_area_level_1" name="administrative_area_level_1" value="" maxlength=30 placeholder='State:*' required>
        <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companystate" id="_HIDDENlead_companystate" value="" entryType="10">
      </SPAN>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companypostcode class=VIEWBOX>
        <input type="text" CLASS=EDIT ID="postal_code" disabled="true" name="country" value="" maxlength=10 placeholder='Post Code:*' required>
        <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companypostcode" id="_HIDDENlead_companypostcode" value="" entryType="10">
      </SPAN>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <SPAN ID="_Datalead_companycountry" class=VIEWBOX>
        <input type="text" CLASS=EDIT ID="country" disabled="true" name="country" value="" maxlength=10 placeholder='Country:*' required>
        <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companycountry" id="_HIDDENlead_companycountry" value="" entryType="10">
      </SPAN>
    </TD>
  </TR>
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bw3c6mdf/2/)

[image: screen shot of result]

**code snippet:**

```js
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
const componentForm = {
  street_number: "short_name",
  route: "long_name",
  locality: "long_name",
  administrative_area_level_1: "short_name",
  country: "long_name",
  postal_code: "short_name",
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

#target {
  width: 345px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Places Search Box</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initAutocomplete&libraries=places&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <SPAN ID=_Datalead_enteryouraddress class=VIEWBOX>
            <input type="text" CLASS=EDIT ID="autocomplete" name="lead_enteryouraddress" value="" maxlength=40 placeholder='Enter your address:*' onFocus="geolocate()" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_enteryouraddress" id="_HIDDENlead_enteryouraddress" value="" entryType="10">
          </SPAN>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companyaddress1 class=VIEWBOX>
            <input type="text" CLASS=EDIT ID="street_number" disabled="true" name="street_number" value="" maxlength=40 placeholder='Street Number:*' required>
            <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companyaddress1" id="_HIDDENlead_companyaddress1" value="" entryType="10">
          </SPAN>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companyaddress2 class=VIEWBOX>
            <input type="text" CLASS=EDIT ID="route" disabled="true" name="route" value="" maxlength=40 placeholder='Street Name:*' required>
            <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companyaddress2" id="_HIDDENlead_companyaddress2" value="" entryType="10">
          </SPAN>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companycity class=VIEWBOX>
            <input type="text" CLASS="jointodesc" disabled="true" ID="locality" name="locality" value="" maxlength=30 placeholder='Suburb:*' required>
            <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companycity" id="_HIDDENlead_companycity" value="" entryType="10">
          </SPAN>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companystate class=VIEWBOX>
            <input type="text" CLASS="EDIT" disabled="true" ID="administrative_area_level_1" name="administrative_area_level_1" value="" maxlength=30 placeholder='State:*' required>
            <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companystate" id="_HIDDENlead_companystate" value="" entryType="10">
          </SPAN>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <SPAN ID=_Datalead_companypostcode class=VIEWBOX>
            <input type="text" CLASS=EDIT ID="postal_code" disabled="true" name="country" value="" maxlength=10 placeholder='Post Code:*' required>
            <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companypostcode" id="_HIDDENlead_companypostcode" value="" entryType="10">
          </SPAN>
      </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <SPAN ID="_Datalead_companycountry" class=VIEWBOX>
            <input type="text" CLASS=EDIT ID="country" disabled="true" name="country" value="" maxlength=10 placeholder='Country:*' required>
            <input type="hidden" name="_HIDDENlead_companycountry" id="_HIDDENlead_companycountry" value="" entryType="10">
          </SPAN>
      </TD>
    </TR>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```